# Samba 4 not working correcty as dns for internal (LAN) addresses

Tags: active-directory, debian, samba, internal-dns

[Edit]

We tried to use samba_internal dns and also bind9_dlz on the server where samba is installed, but both cause problems when trying to access internal addresses even by IP. So we use our DNS, which is a different server. This causes, sometime, problems with authentication, GPO's loading ...
I just want to know how can I fix this strange behavior since it solves external (internet) names/addresses.

I have a Debian Wheezy fully updated with Samba 4.1.17 as and AD. I've been updating/upgrading for months. Years ago the server lost some HDD and the configura was corrupted. in that time trying to solve thing quickly my boss used samba 4 alpha version, if I am not mistaken. He created the new domain, create user by user and group by group again then created the shares and so on.
Some times we had problems with login, solved by rejoin the domain. Things like GPO were not working correctly (most of the time wasn't even working).
Summarizing I did upgrade samba to a stable version and kept upgrading until 4.1.17. Until today even correcting many things with upgrades and changing settings, redoing settings I couldn't solve an annoying DNS problem.

We use samba internal DNS but recently I've tested even with bind9 but the problem to resolve internal names like intranet.enterprise.org. Every internal system we have the same problem. It points to our internal DNS server.
I've even created many times a new server with various samba versions and none presented the same problem. All the tests worked correctly.
All the necessary ports are open.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Your question is a bit chaotic to read, please do some restructuring. From what I gather, you have a separate Samba DNS and "internal DNS". Is the "internal DNS" configured to relay requests to your Samba domain to the Samba server? Can you post some `dig` output that illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All machines here use our internal DNS (bind9) to access internet. It serves internal addresses, external and forwards all to our "provider", the University.

Samba AD works with those as the DNSes but sometimes we can't even join a machine to the domain if we don't change the DNSes to domain's IP. But I was having problems when doing that with some internal addresses, that were not being resolved by Bind9 or Samba internal DNS even when implemented a secondary DC to act as DNS for the AD and to sync configurations. Implementing the second server, as backup, worked for a week correctly, but something in the old server, which can be considered legacy, started to cause problems and the backup started to have the same problems with internal DNS resolution. Don't now why and waste too much time.

So solved using DNSMASQ as described here http://edoceo.com/howto/samba4.
Now everything (!!) is working fine.